# Get rotation of noisy rectangular 2d point cloud with pca

Tags: pca, scikit-learn, scatterplot, numpy, matplotlib

I have a set of point clouds in nd space. The clouds tend to be rectangular in nature in 2d space but can easily have outliers or look slighly L shaped.
I would like to rotate the point clouds so that they line up with the x and y axis.

[image: A noisy rectangular point cloud]

My first thought was to use PCA to find the vectors and rotate accordingly.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

def normalize(d):
    d -= np.min(d, axis=0)
    d /= np.ptp(d, axis=0)
    return d

def correct(some_pointcloud_data):
    a = normalize(np.copy(some_pointcloud_data))

    pca = PCA(n_components=2).fit(a[:, :2])
    theta = pca.components_[0,0]
    c, s = np.arccos(theta), np.arcsin(theta)
    rot = np.array([[c, -s], [s, c]))

    a[:, :2] = normalize(np.matmul(a[:, :2], rot))

    return a
```

This doesn't work though for an obvious reason: **the principle components of a (mostly) rectangular point cloud are in the direction of its corners, not its sides.**

My next guess is that I need to use this found `theta` and some multiple of `np.pi` to rotate the point cloud but this is the part I am stumped on.

Comment: Would adding (or subtracting) 45 degrees to that angle get you an appropriate rotation angle with the cloud of points rotated about the means?

Comment: Maybe I'm having an incompetent day today but for simulated shapes that are very "rectangular", pca is orienting the points as desired (no need to rotate by 45 degrees).  For squares there is much more inconsistency.

Comment: Hmm, I am normalizing the data so that is causing me issues